# iOS - Force full screen video

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using a MPMoviePlayerViewController.  When the video loads and starts playing it doesn't fill up the whole screen.  I have to press the full screen button at the top right to make that happen.  If I use MPMoviePlayerController I can't get it to fill the screen at all.

Any way via code that I can get my video full screen using the MPMoviePlayerViewController without having to press the fullscreen button?

I know i'm using a private API here, but thats ok, it is for a demo.

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"phatpad" ofType:@"mov"];

if (moviePath)
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
}

player.view.frame = self.view.frame;

[self.view addSubview: player.view];

}
```

Here is a screen. The first is without pressing the full screen button, the second is after pressing it.
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to set the fullscreen attribute to true and the scallingMode to the aspect fill like this:

```
if (moviePath)
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    player.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
    player.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
}
```

I have tested at home and it works, so I hope to you too.

Comment: Worked beautifully.  Didn't know I needed to access "moviePlayer".

Comment: Last line should read:

    player.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

Answer (score 0):

On iPhones and iPod Touches, MPMoviePlayerController plays in full screen no matter what, so I'm assuming you're talking about an iPad? Can we please see some code samples? I can make mine full screen simply by resizing the UIView in my XIB file. How are you trying to do it?